# Java Spring Framework Resource Not found IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm getting a really confusing error when trying to make this java/spring web app. It can't seem to find the correct resource and shows a error page when the app runs.

In IntelliJ, the console logs no errors at all, so it's difficult tracking where it's going wrong.

So I even deleted my whole project and decided to follow an online tutorial to the exact letter. And I still get the same runtime error! I'm baffled.

This is what my directory looks like: 
[image: directory]

This is the code for my Controller:

```
package sheridan.assaf.assignment1.demo.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import sheridan.assaf.assignment1.demo.Model.Greeting;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    return "greeting";
}

@PostMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
    return "result";
}

}
```

This is the code for my Greeting class:

```
package sheridan.assaf.assignment1.demo.Model;

public class Greeting {

private long id;
private String content;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

}
```

This is the code for my greeting.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Something to note: in result.html, greeting.id and greeting.content are underlined in red with a "cannot resolve" error in IntelliJ, but this doesn't seem to mean anything because I ran a web app my professor made as an example, and he had the same errors, and his ran just fine.

here's error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would be better if you post your code to github and post a link here. Also it's not clear what URL are you calling.

Comment: Contents of the pom.xml file would be nice to see as well.